# Deserializing multiple fields in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Suppose I have JSON that looks something like this:

```
{ "key1":1, "key2":2, "key3":3 }
```

Where the number of "key-n" fields is unknown, but are consecutively numbered starting at 1.  I wish to deserialize it into an object as follows:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private List<Integer> keys;
}
```

That is, `keys.get(0)` corresponds to the `key1` field, and so on.  The JSON may have other non-"key-n" fields as well.

I had been under the impression that something like

```
public class MyPojo {
    @JsonUnwrapped @JsonDeserialize(using = KeyDeserializer.class) private List<Integer> keys;
}
```

where `KeyDeserializer` is a `JsonDeserializer` would just extract all of the "key-n" fields, would work; however, I had discovered that the deserializer isn't being invoked because the JSON lacks a field named `key`.

Since the JSON is third-party, I can't really try to modify the JSON, so I am wondering if there are any alternate approaches to this problem.

Comment: you can go with `HashMap<String,String>` no need for custom pojo in this case

Comment: That doesn't work in the event that you have to use multiple "key-n" fields or `@JsonAnySetter`, though.

Comment: What do you mean by "the deserializer isn't being invoked because the JSON lacks a field named `key`"?

Comment: There are two issues at hand: one is that there is an UnrecognizedPropertyException being thrown on deserialization for the field `key1`.  The other is that since the JSON has no field named `key`, we will never invoke it, and thus `key1` will never be read.

Comment: Seems like this problem is similar to yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15283502/jackson-deserialization-aggregate-several-fields